# can't display markers using map iterator

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
const places = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "foo",
    latitude: 40.283937,
    longitude: -97.742144
  }
];
```

```
export default class Map extends Component {
...
renderMarkers() {
return places.map(place => (
      <Marker
        key={place.id}
        title={place.title}
        coordinate={{ latitude: place.latitude, longitude: place.longitude }}
        onCalloutPress={e => Actions.details({ text: place.title })}
      />
    ));
}
```

```
import React, { Component, Text } from "react";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import get from "lodash/get";
import { Actions } from "react-native-router-flux";

const Marker = MapView.Marker;

const deltas = {
  latitudeDelta: 0.006866,
  longitudeDelta: 0.01
};

const places = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "foo",
    latitude: 40.283937,
    longitude: -97.742144
  }
];

export default class Map extends Component {
  state = {
    myLocation: null,
    places: [],
    errorMessage: null
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getLocationAsync();
  }

  getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== "granted") {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: "Permission to access location was denied"
      });
    }

    let mylocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    this.setState({ mylocation });
    console.log(this.state.mylocation);
  };

  renderMarkers() {
    return places.map(place => (
      <Marker
        key={place.id}
        title={place.title}
        coordinate={{ latitude: place.latitude, longitude: place.longitude }}
        onCalloutPress={e => Actions.details({ text: place.title })}
      />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    const { mylocation } = this.state;
    const region = {
      latitude: get(mylocation, "coords.latitude"),
      longitude: get(mylocation, "coords.longitude"),
      ...deltas
    };

    return (
      <MapView
        style={styles.mapStyle}
        region={region}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        zoomEnabled={true}
      >
        {this.renderMarkers()}
      </MapView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapStyle: {
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height
  }
});
```

```
Array [
  Object {
    "$$typeof": Symbol(react.element),
    "_owner": FiberNode {
      "tag": 1,
      "key": null,
      "type": [Function Map],
    },
    "_store": Object {},
    "key": "0",
    "props": Object {
      "coordinate": Object {
        "latitude": 40.283937,
        "longitude": -97.742144,
      },
      "onCalloutPress": [Function onCalloutPress],
      "stopPropagation": false,
      "title": "foo",
    },
    "ref": null,
    "type": [Function MapMarker],
  },
]
```

I'm trying to display markers on my react native app using Map.Marker, but it seems like it can't access latitude and longitude of places. places is declared outside the default class Map. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: are you passing prop to map component? show you full code of the map screen

Comment: does it work if you use the number literals (in place of where `place.latitude` and `place.longitude` are)?

Comment: @abhikumar22 I'm not quite sure, but I believe not.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but i think you're also overwriting built in Map constructor with your component.

Comment: @GraceKim what do you get if you console log the values of `place.latitude` & `place.longitude` before you create the `<Marker ... />` component?

Comment: @NickParsons I just found out that it actually gets the correct place.latitude and place.longitude. So, I'd assume it's rather Maker component that's a problem?

Comment: @Clarity Thanks for letting me know. Although I'm not quite sure how to fix that as I don't know much about JavaScript.

Comment: @GraceKim it would seem like it is if that is the case. But if putting the literal numbers in place then it is hard to say exactly what is the cause is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't see markers, it means that component didn't render again.
You can try to use state. If doesn't work, you can try forceUpdate in your renderMarkers method.

```
 state = {
        myLocation: null,
        places: [{
        id: 1,
        title: "foo",
        latitude: 40.283937,
        longitude: -97.742144
      }],
        errorMessage: null
      };

renderMarkers() {
return this.state.places.map(place => (
      <Marker
        key={place.id}
        title={place.title}
        coordinate={{ latitude: place.latitude, longitude: place.longitude }}
        onCalloutPress={e => Actions.details({ text: place.title })}
      />
    ));
}
```